# Can I redirect the browser if the user clicks 'Don't Allow'?

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbml, facebook-authentication

I've implemented a Facebook login on a website, using the Javascript API and FBML.

When the user clicks Login, enters their credentials into the popup window, goes to the next stage and clicks 'Don't Allow' when prompted for permissions, the window simply closes and nothing else happens.

I want to change it so that when the window closes, the browser then redirects to a URL of my choice.

Is this possible with my current setup, using the Javascript API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean XFBML, since you can't use anything except FBJS in FBML. This code is from the [FB.login documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/):

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.session) {
    // user successfully logged in
  } else {
    // user cancelled login
  }
});
```

Whatever goes in that `else` block is what happens if you don't get an authorization. `top.location.href` would work there.

Comment: Works fine, except that I can't differentiate between a user clicking 'Don't Allow' or a user just closing the pop-up. Would be great if I could have different logic if they click 'Don't Allow'. But anyway, that code snippet is very useful, so thanks!

Comment: I see your point, but I'd argue that there really isn't much of a difference anyway. It's not like the pop-up gets closed accidentally; the user closes it with the intention of not seeing it anymore. If you see this and conclude that "oh, they didn't click 'Don't Allow', let me ask them again just to make sure", you're going to have some unhappy users.